# Add column to get the total of values in recursive sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is a recursive query I am using to get details about parts and their sub parts.

```
DECLARE @PartNo Char(22)
DECLARE @PartIssue AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @Level AS INT
DECLARE @PartType AS CHAR(12)
DECLARE @TempLeadTime AS FLOAT
DECLARE @CumLeadTime AS FLOAT 
SELECT @PartIssue = drawissno, @PartNo = partnum, @Level=1, @PartType = sm FROM partmaster  where partnum = 'AE40-0287810'

WITH Hierarchyct(BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty) AS

      (SELECT     @Level AS BOMLevel,
                        @PartNo AS bomchild, 
                        @PartType as parttype,
                        cast('' AS CHAR(22)) AS bomparent,  
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = @PartNo) AS ldtime,
                        @PartIssue as childissue, 
                        eccbom AS bmethod, 
                        eccroute as rmethod,
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS requiredqty

      FROM eccissue 
      WHERE eccpart = @PartNo AND eccissueno = @PartIssue 

      UNION ALL

      SELECT            (hierarchyct.BOMLevel + 1) AS BOMLevel,
                        bom.bomchild, 
                        (SELECT sm from partmaster where partnum = bom.bomchild) as parttype,
                        bom.bomparent, 
                        bom.bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) as ldtime,

                        (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AS childissue,
                        bom.baltmethod AS bmethod,    
                        (SELECT eccroute FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccissueno = (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AND eccissue.eccpart = bom.bomchild ) as rmethod,
                        (bom.bomqty * hierarchyct.requiredqty) AS requiredqty

      FROM bom  INNER JOIN hierarchyct ON bom.bomparent = hierarchyct.bmchild 


      WHERE bom.baltmethod =(SELECT eccbom FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccpart = hierarchyct.bmchild AND eccissue.eccissueno = hierarchyct.childissue )
      )

SELECT   hierarchyct.*,
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.bmqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtime, 
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.requiredqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtimeforRQ 
FROM    hierarchyct left outer join routing on part = bmchild and raltmethod = rmethod left outer join stock on stocknum = bmchild  left outer join partmaster on partnum = Hierarchyct.bmchild 
GROUP BY BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty, stleadtim, sm, part
```

I get a result like the following from this.

[image: query result]

I need to get the total value of all the values in the ldtime column into another column. The reason for this is to calculate the total lead time for a given parent part. Note that all the lead times have to be added. It is enough to have the total value in a single row in the bottom in the other row. How can this be achieved?

Please advise on how to do this. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You results are not specifically ordered *(no `ORDER BY`)*, but for a cumulative column to make sense there needs to be an order to the data.  Also, do you mean to give the cumulative value across all rows, or per BOMLevel or bomchild, etc?  My best advise would be to give some specific examples as to what you do and do not want to achieve.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just want the values added till the end of the column. I don't want an order. Just the running total of the values into a separate column

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, sorry.  For example, if your data was `1, 2, 3, 4` then the running totals would be `1, 3, 6, 10`.  But, if your data was `4, 3, 2, 1` then the running totals would be `4, 7, 9, 10`.  The order of the data matters.  Please give examples and I'll try to help you, but without clear deterministic categorical examples I am unable to do so.  The link I gave to `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` should explain and help you in updating your question.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for pointing that out, it never occurred to me that it doesn't just make sense to get a cumulative total for the ldtime column. It was mentioned in the requirement for a report i am designing, but I guess it was a mistake. I just need to get the total now.

Comment: If you all you need is an extra row with grand total, then run your query twice. First time as it is, second time `SELECT SUM()` and `UNION ALL` two results.

Comment: or select *, (select sum(x) from hierarchyct) as total  from hierarchyct will put the grand total in the last column

Comment: @JulienVavasseur I added ldtime for x and ran the query as you suggested, but it gives an error: `Invalid column name 'ldtime'.`

Comment: isn't it leadTime in your hierarchyct CTE definition at th begining?

Comment: No, it's different. It's the one before the last column in the result, and it is actually calculated by leadtime*runtime